# MINECRAFT FILE DOWNLOAD (MAC)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I ALWAYS WANTED mods but i don't have the mine craft folder i don't know why and how so please help                                                                                                  for mine craft 1.7.4

Comment: in the go menu in finder, hold the option key so that library apears, then navagate to Application support -> minecraft

Answer (score -1):

Type %appdata% in you start search and then click on .minecraft from roaming. Once you done that then you are ready to download mods!

Hope i could help!

Comment: This user is using a Mac for some reason so your answer is not relevant.